# How to fix button not Transforming(Scaling) on Hover

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a button that points to another page on my website and has certain transformations when it is being hovered.

```css
.btn {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  width: 18rem;
  height: 8rem;
  font-family: "Raleway", "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border-radius: 0.1rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}


.btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem black;
}
```

```html
<a href="html/students.html">
   <button class="btn" id="studentbutton">
       Students
   </button>
</a>
```

When I hover over the button, the cursor switches to a pointer, and the box-shadow appears but the transformation(scale) does not occur. I have tried changing the display to 'inline-block for both the link and button but it does not fix my problem.

Could someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: What browser are you using ? It works fine in the snippet.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome. It does not in my webpage. Is there any additional code I can share so you can better diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in the snippet, could be a browser issue, try changing the hover property to:

```
.btn:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  -o-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem black;
}
```

Comment: This still does not fix my problem. I am using Google Chrome.
I don't understand how the snippet works but it does not in the context of my webpage. Is there any additional code I can share that can help you better diagnose the problem?

Comment: May be a caching issue, try a hard refresh with `Ctrl` + `F5`